# How to launch terminal based programs from a program launcher?

Tags: linux, window-manager, application-launch, swaywm

When I'm trying to launch a terminal based software (`lf` or `neovim` for example) using `rofi`/`wofi` or any other launcher, nothing happens.

I'm using `Sway` as a window manager.

Comment: How do you add them exactly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @mashuptwice mostly using a package manager (`pacman` in this case)

Comment: To be listed by Rofi/Wofi launchers, there should be a corresponding `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`.